# showing image in detail page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public with sharing class FacultyPicturePageController {
  public sahi__Faculty__c facultys{get; set;}
  private sahi__Faculty__c fc;
  public ID recId  {get; set;}
  public sahi__Faculty__c currentrecord{get; set;}
  public string fileBody{get;set;}
  public string fileName{get;set;}
  public ApexPages.StandardController controller;
  //private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
  public FacultyPicturePageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    facultys=(sahi__Faculty__c)controller.getRecord();
    //=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    //currentrecord=[SELECT Id FROM sahi__Faculty__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    system.debug('facultys'+facultys);

}

public PageReference saving(){
system.debug('fileName'+fileName);
system.debug('fileBody'+fileBody);
facultys.sahi__Photo__c=fileBody;
//string s=facultys.sahi__Photo__c;

insert facultys;
 PageReference pr;  
if(fileBody != null && fileName != null){
Attachment myAttachment  = new Attachment();  
      myAttachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(fileBody);


      myAttachment.Name = fileName;  
      myAttachment.ParentId =facultys.Id; 
      system.debug(' myAttachment.ParentId'+myAttachment.ParentId);
      myAttachment.contentType = 'application/jpg';
      insert myAttachment;  

       pr = new PageReference('/' + facultys.Id);  
       pr.setRedirect(true);  
       return pr;  
}
pr = new PageReference('/' + facultys.Id);  
       pr.setRedirect(true);  
      return pr;

return null;
}

}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Faculty__c" extensions="FacultyPicturePageController">
<apex:sectionHeader title="New Faculty" subtitle="Faculty Edit"/>
  <apex:form >

  <apex:pageBlock title="Faculty Edit">
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
  <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saving}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="information">
 <apex:inputField value="{!facultys.Email__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!facultys.First_Name__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!facultys.Phone__c}"/>
  <apex:inputFile id="file_File" value="{!fileBody}" filename="{!fileName}"/>               
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and i had created a custom field called photo ,and formula field to show the image in detail page,but in the detail image is not displayed ,kindly check and let me know if any issuses,why it is not displaying the image.iam a fresher.

Comment: Your code has actually _nothing_ to do with a formula field. If the image is displayed through the formula - then check your formula.

Comment: @SergeyUtko the OP is trying to use a custom VF page to upload an image and save it as an attachment.  It's not clear by the way he asks the question but I think he's asking why his code isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097OVIAY) as an example for how to proceed.  Looking at that example it looks like you need to change just a little bit.

First you need to insert the Attachment, then you need to assign your `facultys.sahi__Photo__c` field like the following.

```
facultys.sahi__Photo__c = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+myAttachment.Id;
```

Comment: this is working fine for me,,thanq Doung B.

Comment: Hi Doung B,using this every tym am storing image in database,cant do without saving in database?!

Comment: @sahi The formula you use to display the picture requires a URL, so the picture does have to be saved somewhere.  You could save it on your own servers, or on a hosted site and reference the URL, but how you would determine the URL in such a case would be another issue.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, I agree with @SergeyUkto, the code you posted has nothing to do with formula field on detail page. Please check the formula of the formula field.

To show an image in a field we use the IMAGE() function, So your formula field should contain something like this shown as below.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this,,doesnot help me.